# Error on starting pgadmin3

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, pgadmin-3

When starting pgadmin3 I get the following error messages. This is the log file placed in my documents folder after starting:

> 2018-06-04 13:30:26 ERROR  :
> ERROR:  function pg_last_xlog_receive_location() does not exist
>
> LINE 1: ...E NULL END as inrecovery, CASE WHEN usesuper THEN
> pg_last_xl...
> ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need
> to add explicit type casts. 2018-06-04 13:30:34
> ERROR  : Column not
> found in pgSet: usecreatedb 2018-06-04 13:30:36
> ERROR  : Column not
> found in pgSet: usesuper 2018-06-04 13:30:37
> ERROR  : Column not found
> in pgSet: upsince 2018-06-04 13:30:37
> ERROR  : Column not found in
> pgSet: confloadedsince 2018-06-04 13:30:37
> ERROR  : Column not found
> in pgSet: inrecovery 2018-06-04 13:30:38
> ERROR  : Column not found in
> pgSet: replayloc 2018-06-04 13:30:39
> ERROR  : Column not found in
> pgSet: receiveloc 2018-06-04 13:30:39
> ERROR  : Column not found in
> pgSet: replay_timestamp 2018-06-04 13:30:40
> ERROR  : Column not found
> in pgSet: isreplaypaused 2018-06-04 13:30:41
> ERROR  : Column not found
> in pgSet: rolcatupdate 2018-06-04 13:30:41
> ERROR  : Column not found
> in pgSet: rolcatupdate 2018-06-04 13:30:42
> ERROR  : Column not found
> in pgSet: rolcatupdate 2018-06-04 13:30:43
> ERROR  : Column not found
> in pgSet: rolcatupdate 2018-06-04 13:30:44
> ERROR  : Column not found
> in pgSet: rolcatupdate 2018-06-04 13:30:45
> ERROR  : Column not found
> in pgSet: rolcatupdate

What do I have to do to avoid these errors in the future?
EDIT I am running on MacOS 10.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

You are connecting to PostgreSQL 10, which is not supported.

I am not aware if there is a pgAdmin III version for server version 10 or higher. One choice could be pgAdmin4, or any other client - if you plan to do serious work, consider `psql`, the command line client.

Comment: Actually this also happens for Postgres 9.5.20